# Cannot sign-in to plotly from python script

Tags: python, anaconda, plotly

I am new to Plotly and I am attempting to create a basic graph from the documentation provided on the Plotly site, but when I run my script within Spyder (3.3.1) I get the error message "PlotlyError: Sign in failed.". I am using my username and api key from the .credentials file, so I am unsure of where to go next. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import plotly 
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

#get plotly credentials and store in list
plty_creds = list(py.get_credentials().values())
plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username = plty_creds[0],
                                  api_key = plty_creds[1])

trace0 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[10, 15, 13, 17]
)
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[16, 5, 11, 9]
)
data = [trace0, trace1]

py.sign_in(username = plty_creds[0], api_key = plty_creds[1])

py.plot(data, filename = 'basic-line', auto_open = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

> plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username = plty_creds[0], api_key = plty_creds[2])

Try this

> plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username = plty_creds[0], api_key = plty_creds[1])

Comment: that was a glaring mistake on my part. I've changed it there, but I was using the proper indexing in the ```py.sign_in(username = plty_creds[0], api_key = plty_creds[1])``` line. I made the change you suggested, but can still not log-in

Comment: I have updated the code snippet above to reflect the change in the script